# Can we create objects of a C# class from a VB.NET class in DNN?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dotnetnuke

Can we create objects of a C# class from a VB.NET class and vice versa?

If yes, then how? If no, then why not?

```
edited:-

IN my DNN, i have a user control made in c#, and i am caling a vb class in APP code by creating this 
class obejct, but it don't work in DNN.
```

Comment: Please give actual problem you are facing instead of putting wrong/twisted questions... If you are having problem in DNN then put it as DNN problem and not as `How To Do...` so that someone right person knowing in that might help you in it. and about this you can create dll of C# class and use it in VB and vice versa.

Comment: create separate project for User Control then build it as `Class Library` then add `dll` of that `Class Library` to the DNN project... i don't know much in DNN but I think It seems as `Adding Custom Modules in DNN` sort of thing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. There is nothing special to it. Just instantiate it, like you do with any other class.

Comment: @Novice: What is a DNN framework? And what doesn't happen with it?

Comment: @Cody: I am guessing Dot Net Nuke maybe.

Comment: @Pond: Yeah, I would have guessed that, too. Neither of us will ever know exactly what was meant. And that still doesn't explain why you can't instantiate a Dot Net Nuke class from VB.NET (wasn't it *written* in VB.NET?).

Comment: I did question like that because, that was only the thing i wanted to know and, it should applicable universally, why don.t in DNN.

Answer (score 3):

Yes , you can. Just Add referense to assembly in which that class is